# history.push is changing url but not rendering component in react

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, react-router-dom, history

I am facing a problem with react history.push . The logic of my code is, when the API call completes, if the login status in response is false, I want to push to another route. The URL is changing but the component is not rendering until I refresh the page.

Here is my code for changing the route

```
useEffect(() => {
const getProductsData = async () => {
  setIsLoading(true);
  const productsData = await fetchProductsApi();
  setIsLogin(productsData.data.login);
  setProductsArray(productsData.data.data);
  setIsLoading(false);
  console.log(productsData.data);
  if (productsData.data.login === false) {
    history.push("/");
  }
};
getProductsData(); 
}, [stock]);
```

Here is my code for routes

```
const AuthenticatedRoutes = () => {
return (
  <Router>
    <BottomNavigationMenu />
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/add_product" component={AddNewProduct} />
      <Route path="/add_image/:id" component={AddImage} />
      <Route path="/products" component={Products} />
      <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
  );
  };

return (
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Store} /> 
    <Route path="/product_detail" component={ProductDetail} />
    <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
    <Route exact path="/signin" component={SignIn} />
    <Route component={AuthenticatedRoutes} />      
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Here is my store component

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from "./css/store.module.css"
import SearchIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Search';

const Store = () => {
return ( 
<div className={styles.container}>
    <div className={styles.store_card}>
        <h1 className={styles.store_name}>Fliq shop</h1>
        <h1 className={styles.store_location}>Location</h1>
    </div>
</div>
);
}

export default Store;
```

Comment: can you show your Store component?

Comment: I will edit the question and add store component to it @Yoel

Comment: OK see my answer

Comment: Can you show the result of consoling `history`

Answer (score 1):

i know that my answer is late but i will give my solution to new users:

sometimes is just a problem of version :
check if the version of the history package is the same as the version of react router history

if you use npm :

```
npm list history
```

yarn:

```
yarn list history
```

for me i get that

```
├─ history@5.0.0
├─ react-router-dom@5.2.0
│  └─ history@4.10.1
└─ react-router@5.2.0
   └─ history@4.10.1
```

you notice that the versions differs, so install the same version of react router

```
npm i history@4.10.1
```

yarn

```
yarn add history@4.10.1
```

Comment: This fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

In Store.js add

```
import {withRouter} from 'react-router';
```

```
export default withRouter(Store)
```

also, remove router  Unnecessary

```
//<Router>    remove this line
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Store} /> 
    <Route path="/product_detail" component={ProductDetail} />
    <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
    <Route exact path="/signin" component={SignIn} />
    <Route component={AuthenticatedRoutes} />      
  </Switch>
//</Router>    and remove this line also
```

Comment: I made this change to Store.js, still, the component is not rendering. URL is changing but only if I refresh the page component is rendering.

Comment: @Hadiazeez  can I see your import? 
Does he look like that?
``import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';``

Comment: `import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";` This is the import in app.js. `import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';` This is the import i made now in store.js

Comment: @Hadiazeez  OK good, try to remove router Unnecessary

Comment: Ok, I made that change and it still doesn't render. This happens when routing to routes other than in AuthenticatedRoutes. I made a function AuthenticatedRoutes because, I want bottom navigation to just that routes. When I removed Router it throws error "Invariant failed: You should not use <Switch> outside a <Router>".

Answer (score -1):

There is a new hook useNagivate() you can use that one instead of useHistory

//import

> import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom'

code inside functional component:

> const navigate = useNavigate();

// Where you want to route

> navigate('/something/something');

NOTE: THIS ONLY WORKS on react-router-dom v6 - [more info](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-navigate)